# yahoo weather country and city list

Tags: yahoo

when i need get weather for some city i put this link:
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=713169

But how get all country city code(id)?
Maybe is some xml, rss?

Thanks

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822650/yahoo-weather-api-woeid-retrieval help?

Answer (score 0):

see this: `forecastrss?w=713169`
This `w` parameter is your WOEID. WOEID is invented by yahoo I think and means WehereOnEarthID. So do a google search for WOEID list and you`ll find the answer.