# really good robust jquery weather implementation with user location for feeds

Tags: jquery, yahoo-weather-api

Hey, I have searched all over the place and can't really make up my mind. I have a weather widget installed that pulls weather off yahoo servers but i can't figure out how to do a few things. Successfully switch from DAY to NIGHT images automatically without some sort of hack. and I'm not sure how to pull a 5-day forcast either.

This is what I'm using:

```
    $.YQL = function(query, callback) {
        var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query.toLowerCase()),
        url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodedQuery + '&format=json&callback=?';
        $.getJSON(url, callback);
    };

    $.YQL("SELECT * FROM weather.forecast WHERE location = 93065", function(data){
        var w = data.query.results.channel;

        var d = new Date();
        var curr_hour = d.getHours();
        var dn = (curr_hour < 18 && curr_hour > 4 ? 'd' : 'n');

        var weatherImage = "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/" + w.item.condition.code + dn + ".png";
        var weatherIcon  = "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/" + w.item.condition.code + "s.png";
        $('.weatherImage').html("<img src='" + weatherImage + "' />");
        $('.weatherTemp').html(w.item.condition.temp + "&deg;");
        $('.weatherText').html(w.item.condition.text);

        $(this).everyTime('300s', function(){
            var w = data.query.results.channel;
            var d = new Date();
            var curr_hour = d.getHours();
            var dn = (curr_hour < 18 && curr_hour > 4 ? 'd' : 'n');

            var weatherImage = "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/" + w.item.condition.code + dn + ".png";
            var weatherIcon  = "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/" + w.item.condition.code + "s.png";
            $('.weatherImage').html("<img src='" + weatherImage + "' />");
            $('.weatherTemp').html(w.item.condition.temp + "&deg;");
            $('.weatherText').html(w.item.condition.text);
        });
    }).appendTo('.pin-up-weather');
```

not pretty, but its a short term solution. Has anyone had experience with custom made weather feeds that work pretty dynamically?

I wanted to have the weather just update based on where the user is browsing from but I don't thats possible. I looked at Googles geolocation API but there are no longer in service, things that the maps api took over, but i still wasn't able to figure it out.

if not i'm fine with having the script grab the location from a database depending on what user specifies in their profile.

thanks

Comment: To find the WOEID for a place see the answer posted at: > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822650/yahoo-weather-api-woeid-retrieval

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but I just came across the jQuery plugin [simpleWeather](http://simpleweather.monkeecreate.com/).

It seems to be straight forward.