# Weather for date and lat/lng

Tags: php, web-applications, weather, google-weather-api

I am browsing through a bunch of weather-forecast APIs and none of them seem to do something which I think is pretty necessary.

Is there a way for me to just send an address, or lat/lng coordinates, and the date for the forecast I want (in the future)?

Thank you,
Alex

ps - if it matters, I use PHP.

Comment: Check out the "related" sidebar - there are numerous other questions similar (if not identical) to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [Yahoo weather API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) will do this, but you have to geocode the location to their WOEID first.  You can't specify date, but it appears to return a list of forecasts for upcoming dates.

Comment: I looked into their API, and I don't think you can encode into their WOEID on the fly - can you?  My site's content is user generated, so it must all be dynamically calculated.

Comment: This question addresses how to get WOEID on-the-fly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822650/yahoo-weather-api-woeid-retrieval